# "Index Match" in R Studio (Multiple columns)

Tags: r, excel, rstudio, match, matching

I'm working with a fairly large data set (100k rows) and want to replicate the Excel Index Match function in R Studio.

I'm looking for a way to create a new column that will pull a value from an existing column, if 3 values from three different columns match 3 values from 3 other columns.

Specifically, regarding the example below, I'm looking to create a new column '1994_Number' that pulls the value from '1995_Number' if *all* of the three columns '1994_Address', '1994_ZipCode' and '1994_Bank Name' match '1995_Address', '1995_ZipCode' and '1995_Bank Name'. Desired result in red.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewE05.png)

Any help would be appreciated a lot.

Comment: Hi, it's best to insert data directly into the question instead of posting an image. This makes it easier to follow your thoughts since you don't have to switch between the image and the question).

Comment: You may find it useful to read up these links to help you with writing a reproducible question [ask] and [reprex].

Comment: Thank you. Will do in the future and did so in new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61795811/index-match-in-r-studio-multiple-columns-across-rows. Hope that one is more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution to your problem with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(`1994_Adress` = c("123 Road", "123 Road", "321 Road"),
                  `1994_ZipCode` = c(99999, 99999, 11111),
                  `1994_Bank Name` = c("JPM", "JPM", "WF"),
                  `1995_Adress` = c("123 Road", "1234 Road", "321 Road"),
                  `1995_ZipCode` = c(99999, 99999, 11111),
                  `1995_Bank Name` = c("JPM", "JPM", "WF"),
                  `1995_Number` = c(1, 2, 3), check.names = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(`1994_Number` = case_when(`1994_Adress` == `1995_Adress` & 
                                     `1994_ZipCode` == `1995_ZipCode` &
                                     `1994_Bank Name` == `1995_Bank Name` ~ `1995_Number`))
```

Comment: Does anyone know why the `case_when`function is formated that way in the answer?

Comment: Thank you a lot. Would there be any way so that one does not have to specify the content of the columns ("123 Road",...)? Otherwise I would have to do that for 100,000 rows. I'm looking for a solution that automates that. I'm sorry for only posting a picture and not the data in the post, this is my first post..

Comment: I expect that you have your data in an Excel format. Read the data into R (depending on the data either with `read.csv` or with `read.xlsx`).
After that you only need to change the conditions in `case_when` according to your `colnames`.

Comment: Sorry ---- of course you only create the data frame based on my screenshot! My mistake. I have the csv in R Studio (without the 1994_Number column ofc..). It's called example_2. How can I 'apply' your code to the data frame?

I tried 

example_2 %>%
  mutate(`1994_Number` = case_when(`1994_Address` == `1995_Address` & 
                                     `1994_ZipCode` == `1995_ZipCode` &
                                     `1994_Bank Name` == `1995_Bank Name` ~ `1995_Number`))


Error: 
object '1994_Address' not found

But the column in example2 is called 1994_Address!

Comment: Are you sure your column is called that way? Or does it have a X infront?

Comment: For some reason it didn't work the last time -- now I got the output in the console! It worked. New column 1994_Number created. Thank you so much. One last question: How can I export the output from the console? It does not appear in "example_2" if I click on the data frame to look at it. My goal is basically to export that new column again to csv.

Comment: Edited my answer so it saves the result to the existing df.
If this fully answers your question please mark my response as answer :)

Comment: Hi Nico -- Using the real world data, I encountered another problem. The solution I was looking for should be able to match the three values of year 1994 to the same three values of 1995 *even if they are in another row, and not necessarily the same row* and then return the 1994_Number.

Comment: Dataframe to make that clear: dat <- data.frame(`1994_Adress` = c("1234 Road", "123 Road", "321 Road"),
+                   `1994_ZipCode` = c(99999, 99999, 11111),
+                   `1994_Bank Name` = c("JPM", "JPM", "WF"),
+                   `1995_Adress` = c("123 Road", "1234 Road", "321 Road"),
+                   `1995_ZipCode` = c(99999, 99999, 11111),
+                   `1995_Bank Name` = c("JPM", "JPM", "WF"),
+                   `1995_Number` = c(1, 2, 3), check.names = F, stringsAsFactors = F) 

1994_Number should be (2,1,3) as a result

Comment: Nico - I posted a new question for this, so happy to mark your response there as the correct answer again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61795811/index-match-in-r-studio-multiple-columns-across-rows