# "Index Match" In R Studio (multiple columns, across rows)

Tags: r, excel, rstudio, match, matching

I'm working with a fairly large data set (100k rows) and want to replicate the Excel Index Match function in R Studio.

I'm looking for a way to create a new column that will pull a value from an existing column ("1995_Number"), if 3 values from three different columns from one year match three values from three columns from another year - *independent of the rows*, and create a new column ("1994_Number").

Dataframe as example:

`` dat <- data.frame(`1994_Address` = c("1234 Road", "123 Road", "321 Road"),
                  `1994_ZipCode` = c(99999, 99999, 11111),
                  `1994_Bank Name` = c("JPM", "JPM", "WF"),
                  `1995_Address` = c("123 Road", "1234 Road", "321 Road"),
                  `1995_ZipCode` = c(99999, 99999, 11111),
                  `1995_Bank Name` = c("JPM", "JPM", "WF"),
                  `1995_Number` = c(1, 2, 3), check.names = F, stringsAsFactors = F) ``

The newly created column 1994_Number should say (2, 1, 3)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would include the `match` function from `base`. Toghether with `dplyr` the following works:

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(`1994_Adress` = c("1234 Road", "123 Road", "321 Road"),
                  `1994_ZipCode` = c(99999, 99999, 11111),
                  `1994_Bank Name` = c("JPM", "JPM", "WF"),
                  `1995_Adress` = c("123 Road", "1234 Road", "321 Road"),
                  `1995_ZipCode` = c(99999, 99999, 11111),
                  `1995_Bank Name` = c("JPM", "JPM", "WF"),
                  `1995_Number` = c(1, 2, 3), check.names = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
dat %>%
  mutate(`1994_Number` = ifelse(`1994_Adress` %in% `1995_Adress` & 
                                  `1994_ZipCode` %in% `1995_ZipCode` &
                                  `1994_Bank Name` %in% `1995_Bank Name`, 
                                dat[match(dat$`1994_Adress`, dat$`1995_Adress`), "1995_Number"], NA))

#    1994_Adress 1994_ZipCode 1994_Bank Name 1995_Adress 1995_ZipCode 1995_Bank Name 1995_Number 1994_Number
# 1   1234 Road        99999            JPM    123 Road        99999            JPM           1           2
# 2    123 Road        99999            JPM   1234 Road        99999            JPM           2           1
# 3    321 Road        11111             WF    321 Road        11111             WF           3           3
```

Comment: Sadly, the code does not work when I apply it to my own data set. Error: Error: 'vec_dim' is not an exported object from 'namespace:vctrs'

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of [this issue](https://github.com/r-lib/vctrs/issues/487) could help?

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting an output now. But now in my data set, for the equivalent "1994_Number" the type is '<list>' and in the console it says '<dbl [176]' for each value (my data has 176 rows). In the data frame viewer it says 'c(278300, 42855, 180753, 4,......). It seems to put all of the output for the variable into a list and put that in each output 'cell'...

Comment: Hi @maxfrie.
This is really hard to figure out without a big enough sample data from you.
If I run the code i get no error, it is still a df.
Mind to provide more data?

Comment: Hey @nico -- Had to focus my attention on another project over the last days. Yes, providing that would be amazing. How can I do so? Would I be able to contact you privately?

Comment: would appreciate it a lot if you would have further thoughts.

Comment: Hi @maxfrie sorry for not responding earlier. Sure, if you give me any way to contact you privately I will try to solve your problem (if you don't have so already)